# Pre-Build/Post-Build Events in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: visual-studio-mac, post-build-event

I'm pretty new to Visual Studio, and I can't seem to find where to go to find pre and post build events. I know how to do it on Windows, but i'm on Mac currently and it seems to work differently. If anyone could help to direct me that would be great! I'm specifically looking for post-build events, but I would assume they are in the same place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the Project's Options and goto:

`Build` / `Custom Commands` / `Select a project operation`

[image]